# How to add a link to an executable to a solution in order to launch it

Tags: c#, batch-file, hyperlink, executable, solution

I have a solution with several projects. When developing I need to switch from one to another very often sometimes not for changing the code but only to change some files.

It would be very useful therefore to have in the solution a link to those executable or batch files in order to launch them.

I know that executable or batch files can be added by alt+dragging/dropping or add external files--> add as a link. I can do that easily.

What I can't do is to launch them with the mouse from the solution after having added them.

Comment: Do you want to execute those scripts after each build of a certain project or randomly for the entire solution?

Comment: No sorry I didn't make it clear. I want to execute them upon my mouse click.

Comment: That was clear allready. The question was more on the circumstances of your your click. Is the task related to any event? E.g. a check-out of your solution? A build on a certain project? Whatever? Anyway I can´t see why you can´t simply execute those processes from a shell e.g.

Comment: [Vs code workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) allows your to have multi root workspaces.

Comment: @HimBromBeere. No those executable or batch files are to be launched upon random conditions. E.g. I am debugging Proj1 but I need some files to be modified by the executable in Proj2. So instead of having all the times to 1.stop Proj1 then   2. set Proj2 as startup project   3. launch Proj2    4. modifiy those files    5. stop Proj2    6. set Proj1 as startup  project   7. relaunch Proj1     I would prefer 1. keep Proj1 then  2. modifiy files

Comment: You don´t have to set the startup-project every time you want to execute your program. You can simply right-click in Solution Explorer and click Debug--> Start new instance. Furthermore you can debug more projects in paralell, not only one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the start new instance thing!! That is very useful and solves the problem. One last little problem might be that I have a deployment batch and it might be useful to have it in the solution and launch it directly. Any idea?